# Designing domain models for hierarchical data (in DDD)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ddd

It is my first attempt in DDD and I'm trying to wrap my head about this concept. In my examples a lot of validation is omitted for simplicity. I have two types of InterfaceConfigurations:

- VistaLink: outbound interface (must have EndPoint specified, i.e. where outgoing messages go)
- HL7: can be inbound (no need for EndPoint) or outbound (requires EndPoint and FacilityID)

The following how I addressed it in the code. But I wonder if that is too much of inheritance on domain models level (I've seen a number advises to avoid it):

Shared properties are in the base class:

```
public class InterfaceConfiguration: IEntity<string>
{
    public InterfaceConfiguration(string id, string displayName, bool isActive, bool isRequired, InterfaceTypeEnum interfaceType)
    {
        Id = id;
        DisplayName = displayName;
        IsActive = isActive;
        IsRequired = isRequired;
        InterfaceType = interfaceType;
    }
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; protected set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; protected set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; protected set; }
    public InterfaceTypeEnum InterfaceType { get; protected set; }
}
```

Inbound Hl7 interface with its properties:

```
public class Hl7InterfaceConfiguration : InterfaceConfiguration
{
    public Hl7InterfaceConfiguration(string id, string displayName, bool isActive, bool isRequired,
        string fieldSeparator, char[] encodingCharacters, char processingId, string versionId):  //there are acually more properties...
        base(id, displayName, isActive, isRequired, InterfaceTypeEnum.Hl7)
    {
        FieldSeparator = fieldSeparator;
        EncodingCharacters = encodingCharacters;
        ProcessingId = processingId;
        VersionId = versionId;
    }
    public string FieldSeparator { get; protected set; }
    public char[] EncodingCharacters { get; protected set; }
    public char ProcessingId { get; protected set; }
    public string VersionId { get; protected set; }
}
```

VistaLink interface:

```
public class VistaLinkInterfaceConfiguration : InterfaceConfiguration
{
    public VistaLinkInterfaceConfiguration(string id, string displayName, bool isActive, bool isRequired, IntrefaceEndPoint endPoint)
        : base(id, displayName, isActive, isRequired, InterfaceTypeEnum.VistaLink)
    {
        if (endPoint == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(endPoint));
        if (endPoint.AddressType != EndPointAddressTypeEnum.DnsHostName && endPoint.AddressType != EndPointAddressTypeEnum.IPAddress)
            throw new ArgumentException("Address type muct be DnsHostName or IPAddress", nameof(endPoint));
    }

    public IntrefaceEndPoint EndPoint { get; protected set; }
}
```

And finally outbound Hl7 interface:

```
public class Hl7OutboundInterfaceConfiguration : Hl7InterfaceConfiguration
{
    public Hl7OutboundInterfaceConfiguration(string id, string displayName, bool isActive, bool isRequired,
        string fieldSeparator, char[] encodingCharacters, char processingId, string versionId, IntrefaceEndPoint endPoint, string facilityId)
        : base(id, displayName, isActive, isRequired, fieldSeparator, encodingCharacters, processingId, versionId)
    {
        if (endPoint == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(endPoint));
        if (endPoint.AddressType != EndPointAddressTypeEnum.DnsHostName && endPoint.AddressType != EndPointAddressTypeEnum.IPAddress)
            throw new ArgumentException("Address type must be DnsHostName or IPAddress", nameof(endPoint));

        if (facilityId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Facility ID is required for HL7 outbound interface", nameof(facilityId));
        }
    }

    public IntrefaceEndPoint EndPoint { get; protected set; }
    public string FacilityId { get; protected set; }
}
```

I tried to make it more "flat", but not sure how. For example, *EndPoint* and *FacilityID* properties of *Hl7OutboundInterfaceConfiguration* don't make sense for *Hl7InterfaceConfiguration* (which is inbound only). So that would expose them in unassigned state for *Hl7InterfaceConfiguration* and potentially may confuse outer functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't You try to use **composition over inheritance**

Inheritance is when you design your types around what they are and composition is when you design your types around what they do.

```
interface IFacilities
{
   public string FacilityId { get; set; }
}

interface IOutgoing
{
    public IntrefaceEndPoint EndPoint { get; protected set; }
}
```

and then

```
public class Hl7OutboundInterfaceConfiguration : IFacilities, IOutgoing
{}

public class Hl7InterfaceConfiguration 
{}
```